# Building PCA components on arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pca

I'm trying to build principal components on array rows across multiple columns-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 10), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
df['arr1'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].values.tolist()
df['arr2'] = df[['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']].values.tolist()

df['arr1'] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df['arr1']]
df['arr2'] = [preprocessing.scale(row) for row in df['arr2']]
df

X = df.loc[:, 'arr1':'arr2']
pca = PCA(.95)
pca.fit(X)
pca.transform(X)
```

Which gives the error-

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried converting arr1 and arr2 by `np.array(list(df.arr1))` but this just maintains the first value from each array.

In my real dataset, there are 200-300 elements in each array.

Comment: I am guessing the error is on the line `df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].values.tolist()` which  is a sequence and so you cannot set a dataframe column to it. Describe your data a bit more. What are these columns and what are you trying to achieve with `df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].values.tolist()`?

Comment: Try using `df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].values` instead of `df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].values.tolist()`. You will get a 2D array instead of a list.

Comment: @manu190466 gives the error- ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

Answer (score 0):

`fit` and `transform` needs a 2D array input, what you are passing isn't one.
This works:

```
arr = [X.loc[0]['arr1'].tolist(), X.loc[0]['arr2'].tolist()]
pca.fit(arr)
pca.transform(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I build components within the array across multiple columns? In my real dataset, each array has 200-300 elements, 15 such columns and ~1000 rows. I am able to build pcs on each individual column using pca.transform(np.array(list(df.arr1))). But I want to gather all columns at once into 1 variable (X) and perform pca for each column.